# how to get the value of json object which i have saved in sharedpreference from one activity to another activity?

Tags: android, json

This is first activity through which i'm saving data in sharedpreferences...

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);

public static String userid;
userid = obj.getString("userid");
String otp = obj.getString("opt");

SharedPreferences sp=getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("SharedPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

Editor editor = sp.edit();
editor.putString("userid", userid);
editor.putString("opt", otp.toString());
editor.commit();
```

and i want the value of userid in second activity...

```
SharedPreferences sp = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("Sharedprefs",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String userid = sp.getString("userid","");
String otp = sp.getString("opt", "");
```

i want the value of "userid" and "otp" which have been stored in "SharedPrefs" sharedprefs, and i dont want to give any default value for this....

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If above is your code you should change `Sharedprefs` in the second Preferences to `SharedPrefs`.

Answer (score 0):

When you store data in `SharedPreferences`, make sure that Preference name is spelled correctly. It is case sensitive.

Find the difference between **"Sharedprefs"** and **"SharedPrefs"**.

Try this way.

```
SharedPreferences sp = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("SharedPrefs",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String userid = sp.getString("userid","");
String otp = sp.getString("opt", "");
```